# Query on ethers.provider in hardhat-ethers

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

how to use **provider** while using ethers from **hardhat-ethers**?? How can i use all methods from [here](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/provider/-%23-Provider) while using **ethers** from **hardhat-ethers**??

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` you can access it either importing it from hardat:

```
import { ethers} from 'hardhat'
```

or you can import/receive the hre (hardhat runtime environment):

```
import * as hre from 'hardhat'
const ethers = hre.ethers,
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it same as ethers.js documentation?

Comment: I don't know, yet all of the methods I used on ethers are available and what is really handy, you receive the signer and accounts on local node teting

Comment: what is difference between ethers.getSinger and ethers.provider.getSigner?

Comment: ethers.getSigner() is not available on ethers.js, but  available on hardhat.ethers and allows you to query the current signer on your local hardhat node.

ethers.provider.getSigner() will return you the signer of your ether connection to the blockchain